# Split file into specific output filenames by pattern match

Tags: csplit

I have a file with this content:

```
# new file
text in file 1
# new file
text in file 2
# new file
text in file 3
```

The pattern here is `# new file`.

I instead of saving each file to xx00, xx01 and xx02, save to specific files: `another file`, `file new`, `last one`.

The 3 files exist in current directory, so I want to provide them as array, overwrite them:

```
csplit -z infile '/# new file/' "${array[*]}"
```

The array can be provided directly

```
array=('another file' 'file new' 'last one')
echo ${array[*]}
another file file new last one
```

Or list current directory

```
array=($(find . -type f))
echo ${array[*]}
./another file ./file new ./last one
```

A modification of [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58637487/2394635) could be the solution:

```
awk -v file="1" -v occur="2" '
{
  print > (file".txt")
}
/^\$\$\$\$$/{
  count++
  if(count%occur==0){
    if(file){
      close(file".txt")
      ++file
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works even with spaces and non ascii characters, both inside the text file and the filenames, without using temp files:

`infile`:

```
# new file
text in file1

blabla
# new file
text in file2
# new file
text in file3

$//*+\

s
# new file
4!
aaaaaaaaa
i^
# new file

#¬}}{][|\~@
```

The awk command must be provided with the filenames as individual arguments, using single quotes so does not shell expand (double quotes), in this `split.sh` script:

```
awk -v file="0" '
  BEGIN { 
    print "AWK arguments:"
    for (i = 0; i < ARGC; i++){
    ARRAY[i] = ARGV[i]
    print "\047"ARRAY[i]"\047"
    if (i > 1){
      ARGV[i] = ""
    }
  }
  print "Writing:"
}
!/^# new file$/{
  print "writing to: " "\047"ARRAY[file+1]"\047"
  print $0 >> ARRAY[file+1]
}
/^# new file$/{
  close(file)
  ++file
  print "writing to: " "\047"ARRAY[file+1]"\047"
  print $0 > ARRAY[file+1]
}
' 'infile' '1.txt' '2.txt' '3.txt' 'file $_%.txt' '&file  _.txt'
```

The console looks like this:

```
AWK arguments:
'awk'
'infile'
'1.txt'
'2.txt'
'3.txt'
'file $_%.txt'
'&file  _.txt'
Writing:
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: 'file $_%.txt'
writing to: 'file $_%.txt'
writing to: 'file $_%.txt'
writing to: 'file $_%.txt'
writing to: '&file  _.txt'
writing to: '&file  _.txt'
writing to: '&file  _.txt'
```

If the arguments are passed as the output from another command (files must exist previously in the filesystem):

```
' $(ls infile | tr '\n' ' ' ; ls *.txt)
```

it splits the arguments by the space:

```
AWK arguments:
'awk'
'infile'
'&file'
'_.txt'
'1.txt'
'2.txt'
'3.txt'
'_.txt'
'file'
'$_%.txt'
Writing:
writing to: '&file'
writing to: '&file'
writing to: '&file'
writing to: '&file'
writing to: '_.txt'
writing to: '_.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
```

To solve that pass the arguments as an array to awk, separated by a newline and not a space, with this `split.sh` script:

```
array=(infile *.txt)
awk -v file="0" '
  BEGIN { 
    print "AWK arguments:"
    for (i = 0; i < ARGC; i++){
    ARRAY[i] = ARGV[i]
    print "\047"ARRAY[i]"\047"
    if (i > 1){
      ARGV[i] = ""
    }
  }
  print "Writing:"
}
!/^# new file$/{
  print "writing to: " "\047"ARRAY[file+1]"\047"
  print $0 >> ARRAY[file+1]
}
/^# new file$/{
  close(file)
  ++file
  print "writing to: " "\047"ARRAY[file+1]"\047"
  print $0 > ARRAY[file+1]
}
' "${array[@]}"
```

Now the result is:

```
AWK arguments:
'awk'
'infile'
'&file  _.txt'
'1.txt'
'2.txt'
'3.txt'
'file $_%.txt'
Writing:
writing to: '&file  _.txt'
writing to: '&file  _.txt'
writing to: '&file  _.txt'
writing to: '&file  _.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '1.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '2.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: '3.txt'
writing to: 'file $_%.txt'
writing to: 'file $_%.txt'
writing to: 'file $_%.txt'
```

The number of files to write to, must be at least the same as splits which will be performed. If more, the rest will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I would still consider using `csplit`, but then rename the generated files afterwards.

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir ".tmp.$$" || exit 2
csplit -f ".tmp.$$/tmp_" -zk -n 4 "$1" '/# new file/' '{*}'

for file in ".tmp.$$"/tmp_*
do
    shift
    mv -f "$file" "$1"
done
if ! rmdir ".tmp.$$" 2>/dev/null
then
    echo "Warning: not all file parts were assigned" >&2
    rm -rf ".tmp.$$"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Usage

```
mysplit <source_file> <target_names...>
```